# finding max possible date in ms sql server 2005+

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a function like `GETDATE()` in Sql Server 2005 that let's you get the max possible date?

I do not want to find the highest date in a table. I want to get the max possible date that sql server will be able to store.

Basically, I want an expiration date of never

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) says the range is January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999.

I don't think there is a built in function, but you could create one that returns the maximum datetime value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_max_date
RETURNS datetime
AS
return cast('12/31/9999 23:59:59.9999' as datetime)
```

Comment: I've always thought these were very odd choices.  I'd much rather be able to use years before 1753 rather than years after, say, 2400.

Comment: I think its because of problems with which countries switch to Gregorian calendar for dates earlier than 1753

Comment: The accuracy is also strange, the documentation says it's "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds"

Comment: Kristen is correct, one of the reasons for not allowing dates older than 1753 is because calendars weren't standard back then.

datetime data types round to 3ms in SQL Server.  For greater control use the new data types in SQL 2008+.

Comment: As Tommy Heath mentions in his answer, attempting to cast '12/31/9999 23:59:59.9999' results in an out of range value error (at least in SQL 2008). According to the docs, the max *time* value of a datetime is "23:59:59.997" - so using ".999~" would try to round it up to the next day, in the year 10000!

Comment: While the general structure of this is correct there are issues. It will only work if the region of the server is set to US, and the precision of the datetime used is incorrect.

Comment: What happens if you have a method incrementing the date? Does it always throw an error, or are there situations in which it wraps back to 1753?

Answer (score 14):

`CAST()` seems to be dependent on the SQL Server language/culture.

On my **German** SQL Servers 2008 R2 and 2012 (`@@language = 'Deutsch'`), the following cast throws an error:

```
CAST('12/31/9999 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME)
```

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Whereas this one works just fine:

```
CAST('31.12.9999 23:59:59.997' AS DATETIME)
```

**SOLUTION**

I think the safest approach is to specify the format with `CONVERT()`:

```
/* ISO 8601 */
CONVERT(DATETIME, '9999-12-31T23:59:59.997', 126)
```

Comment: Upvoted as for use of correct date formats - ie ISO8601 UTC

Comment: Your answer, especially the convert one helped me :) Thank you

Answer (score 13):

In my SQL Server 2008 r2, I get these odd results (not that I'm ever going to miss those 3 milleseconds)

```
SELECT cast('12/31/9999 23:59:59.997' as datetime) --RETURNS '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997'
SELECT cast('12/31/9999 23:59:59.998' as datetime) --RETURNS '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997'
SELECT cast('12/31/9999 23:59:59.999' as datetime) --RETURNS The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Comment: This looks like a observation not an answer

Comment: The documentation also states [Accurancy is Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx)

Comment: I just wasted a whole afternoon trying to find a bug when using C# ```DateTime.MaxValue``` due to  SQL rounding up the last value. That's what you get when you don't consider the errors you get.

Answer (score 9):

Consult the documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

```
Date range
January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999
```

There is no way to get the max datetime programatically.

If so it would be listed here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Answer (score 8):

I'm creating a new answer to this question just to address a couple of minor issues with scottm's otherwise good accepted answer.

1. According to the docs, the maximium value of the *time* component of a `datetime` is actually "23:59:59.**997**", so using a value of "23:59:59.999" will actually round up to midnight the following day. Where the date part is already given as 31st Dec 9999 this would attempt to round up to 1st Jan 10000 which gives an out-of-range error.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819(v=sql.105).aspx says:

> Date range: January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999
>
> Time range: 00:00:00 through 23:59:59.997

2. The date literals used are in US format, and while these are not ambiguous for 31st Dec it's best to use ISO format. Nitpicky maybe, but I find reading dates in mm/dd/yyyy format very non-intuitive, and I suspect I'm not alone.
3. SQL needs the body of the function to be contained in a BEGIN/END block, so as written the example could not be created.

So my improved version of the max DateTime function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnMaxDateTime()
RETURNS DateTime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST('9999-12-31 23:59:59.997' AS DateTime)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want an expiration date of "never", it might be better to store NULL rather than an arbitrary far-future date. While it is unlikely that the date will reach year 9999 without the code being "fixed", it is an illogical value to store for EndDate = never.

Comment: It isn't terribly useful for writes but is useful for reads e.g. "WHERE val < ISNULL(@d, maxdate())" because it improves index utilization - http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/18/sql-conditional-where-clauses.aspx

Comment: this approach would nullify indexed searches on this field. the most performant way is always avoiding nullable columns if performance is important as this would allow queries to fully utilize indexes. Besides queries also become easier to construct where you don't have to remember to add (OR xxx IS NULL) clause to the end.

Comment: I would argue that for all or most practical use cases @KemalErdogan is correct in that having better/more consistent index utilization is better than optimizing for "semantics". While having an end_date of `null` semantically makes the most sense for something that never expires, the idea is easily conveyed/understood by a year of 9999. It also does simplify query conditions as well, which is another benefit of avoiding the NULL in this (and other) cases.

Answer (score 0):

Not a viable solution in a production environment, but you could increment the date until you hit the out-of-bounds error and catch the result:

```
BEGIN TRY  
    DECLARE
        @Step_Cnt INT = 0
        , @Ms_Increment int = 0
        , @StartDate datetime = '9999-12-31T23:59:59.900'
        , @CurDate datetime
        , @MaxTries int = 10000;
        set @CurDate = @StartDate
    WHILE TRY_CONVERT( datetime, @CurDate ) is not null and @Step_Cnt < @MaxTries
    BEGIN
        /* handle variable accuracy "Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds" */
        set @Ms_Increment = 0
        WHILE dateadd( millisecond, @Ms_Increment, @CurDate ) = @CurDate 
        BEGIN
            SET @Ms_Increment = @Ms_Increment + 1;
            SET @CurDate = dateadd( millisecond, @Ms_Increment, @CurDate )
        END;
        set @Step_Cnt = @Step_Cnt + 1
    END;
    select 'OK' as [Status],@StartDate as [StartDate], @Step_Cnt as [NumSteps], @CurDate as [FinalDate]

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    select 'Caught' as [Status],@StartDate as [StartDate], @Step_Cnt as [NumSteps], @CurDate as [FinalDate]
END CATCH;
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
    Select CAST(2958463 as DATETIME)
```

This translates to 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000