# SQL Server function to return minimum date (January 1, 1753)

Tags: sql-server, datetime, function

I am looking for a SQL Server function to return the minimum value for datetime, namely January 1, 1753. I'd rather not hardcode that date value into my script.

Does anything like that exist? (For comparison, in C#, I could just do `DateTime.MinValue)`
Or would I have to write this myself?

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you planning to use that date at all as opposed to letting the column be NULL instead?

Comment: You could use `CONVERT(smalldatetime, 0)` for `smalldatetime`.

Comment: CONVERT(smalldatetime, 0) or CONVERT(datetime, 0) or  cast(0 as datetime) is not minimum value of datetime

Comment: @Joe: The column does not allow NULL values, and I don't want to change it since I am not creating this table.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You could write a [User Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164062.aspx) that returns the min date value like this:

```
select cast(-53690 as datetime)
```

Then use that function in your scripts, and if you ever need to change it, there is only one place to do that.

Alternately, you could use this query if you prefer it for better readability:

```
select cast('1753-1-1' as datetime)
```

**Example Function**

```
create function dbo.DateTimeMinValue()
returns datetime as
begin
    return (select cast(-53690 as datetime))
end
```

**Usage**

```
select dbo.DateTimeMinValue() as DateTimeMinValue

DateTimeMinValue
-----------------------
1753-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid writing my own, but it looks like that is my only option.

Comment: If you're going to have an arbitrary constant, `'1753-1-1'` is much better than `-53690`

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, I was thinking the same thing. Coming back to the script, I would have no idea what -53690 means.

Comment: The function name would make obvious the meaning of the value.

Comment: There is no function even in SQL Server 2012 to get min date similar to getdate() hence the above one is the only possible solution.  This is for anyone who is looking for better solution in sql server 2012 related solution.

Comment: Just use DateTime2(7).  It maps to the .NET DateTime type exactly.  Using sql 'datetime' is a bad as using 'varchar' instead of 'nvarchar'.  'nvarchar' aligns with .NET String type.  Same idea.  Then you can just use DateTime.MinValue everywhere.

Comment: @Gabe using the -53690 value will make the code agnostic on regional settings though.

Comment: As mentioned by Frank Gillich below, `cast('17530101' as datetime)` will also avoid the regional issues and is slightly more readable than -53690.

Comment: OP wanted to avoid hard-coding a constant in his script.  This proposed answer still has a hard-coded constant.  It might not have to be embedded in each script, but would have to be embedded in some user-written script.

Comment: @RedFilter - Agreed, this is a stupid incompleteness in SQL Server API, but your answer does not avoid the constraint imposed by OP, simply moves the workaround to another place in his/her script.  Consequently, not a totally acceptable answer.

Comment: just to have this linked, related (max): https://stackoverflow.com/a/548373/1132334

Comment: NOTE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39541331/199364 says that `cast('17530101'` avoids regional issues, so use that instead of `cast('1753-1-1'`.

Answer (score 29):

Have you seen the [SqlDateTime object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.aspx)? use `SqlDateTime.MinValue` to get your minimum date (Jan 1 1753).

Comment: This needs to be a SQL function, not a .NET function.

Comment: Although SqlDateTime.MinValue is useful, it's deceptive to have this as an answer. @Jeremy is asking for a native sql function, not something from .NET's class library

Comment: plus one for this helped with a similar question but in a .Net context not SQL; as it is the case with this question..

Comment: Maybe you can actually achieve this by using the new [U-SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/09/28/introducing-u-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

As I can not comment on the accepted answer due to insufficeint reputation points my comment comes as a reply.

using the `select cast('1753-1-1' as datetime)` is due to fail if run on a database with regional settings not accepting a datestring of YYYY-MM-DD format.

Instead use the `select cast(-53690 as datetime)` or a `Convert` with specified datetime format.

Answer (score 9):

Enter the date as a native value `'yyyymmdd'` to avoid regional issues:

```
select cast('17530101' as datetime)
```

Yes, it would be great if TSQL had `MinDate() = '00010101'`, but no such luck.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fast and highly readable way to get the min date value

Note: This is a [Deterministic Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017), so to improve performance further we might as well apply WITH SCHEMABINDING to the return value.

**Create a function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION MinDate()
RETURNS DATETIME WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT(DATETIME, -53690)

END
```

**Call the function**

```
dbo.MinDate()
```

**Example 1**

```
PRINT dbo.MinDate()
```

**Example 2**

```
PRINT 'The minimimum date allowed in an SQL database is ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), dbo.MinDate())
```

**Example 3**

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateValue > dbo.MinDate()
```

**Example 4**

```
SELECT dbo.MinDate() AS MinDate
```

**Example 5**

```
DECLARE @MinDate AS DATETIME = dbo.MinDate()

SELECT @MinDate AS MinDate
```

Answer (score 5):

It's not January 1, 1753 but select cast('' as datetime) wich reveals: 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 gives the default value by SQL server. 
(Looks more uninitialized to me anyway)

Comment: This is not correct. The base datetime is 1 Jan 1900 00:00:00.000 (what you get with `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 0)`) but the actual minimum value that datetime can hold in SQL Server is actually in 1753 what OP wrote. That‘s when America also switched to the Gregorian calender and SQL Server doesn‘t have to deal with missing days etc. `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, -53690)` gives `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000` and `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, -53691)` gives an error about an overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to get the minimum date in SQL Server. Please note that it is globalisation friendly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateTimeMinValue]()
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT
    CAST('17530101' AS datetime))
END
```

Call using:

```
SELECT [dbo].[DateTimeMinValue]()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
declare @dateTimeMin as DATETIME = datefromparts(1753, 1, 1);
select @dateTimeMin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The following code is not pretty. It is not a best practice to rely on Try/Catch statments. It also does not meet the requirement of the original poster for it to be a function since *functions may not contain Try/Catch statements*.

That being said, the following SQL code **will** give you the Minimum date or Maximum date (*bonus*) **without using any magic numbers**. It runs fast enough so as long as you don't embed it in a loop, speed won't be an issue. I show the statements here as one line of code so they can be easily copy/pasted and inserted into a stored procedure without using up a lot of space and distracting from the main SP itself.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATETIME, 0); BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SELECT @MinDate = DateAdd(YEAR, -1, @MinDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;
SELECT @MinDate

DECLARE @MaxDate DATETIME = GETDATE(); BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(HOUR,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(MINUTE,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(SECOND,1,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH; BEGIN TRY WHILE (1=1) BEGIN SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(ms,3,@MaxDate); END END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;
SELECT @MaxDate
```

Answer (score -2):

The range for `datetime` will not change, as that would break backward compatibility.  So you can hard code it.

Comment: That is true, but it would still be nice to call GetMinDate() or something like that instead of CONVERT(datetime, '1753-1-1') wherever I needed to use it.

Comment: @Jeremy: I know what `convert` does, but for `GetMinDate()` I'd have to dive into the function definition.  So if I had to maintain your code, I'd prefer the `convert` variant.

Comment: You might know what `convert` does, but you wouldn't necessarily know the significance of `1753-1-1`.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the objection to having to dive into the function. Its ALWAYS more maintainable to NAME special values. "Magic Numbers" are bad for maintainability. Another downside of hardcoding it everywhere you need it, is the possibility of a typo. Suppose you accidentally type `CONVERT(datetime, '17540101') once. Would be easy to overlook, and might work for most purposes. But someday cause misbehavior by code that is checking for '17530101'. A lurking bug.