# Getting Maximum Datetime Value Programmatically

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I retrieve the maximum value of the `DATETIME` data type in SQL Server 2005 programmatically? I don't want to use `NULL` as the column value, and I don't want to use `CONVERT(DATETIME, '12/31/9999 23:59:59.997')` either.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the problem with using the hard coded maximum value of '12/31/9999 23:59:59.997'? It's not like it's ever going to change.

Comment: Um, Joe, it DID change between SQL Server 2005 and 2008! SQL Server 2005  Min Date: 1753-01-01 00:00:00.000,  Max Date: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999. SQL Server 2008  Min Date: 0001-01-01 00:00:00.000, Max Date: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding max possible date in ms sql server 2005+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548353/finding-max-possible-date-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Comment: @DOK: Perhaps you're thinking of the introduction of the new `DATETIME2` datatype in 2008? The accepted range for `DATETIME` did not change.

Comment: @DOK: it will never change for SQL Server 2005 anyway

Comment: Oops, I was relying on the [first Google result](http://sqlserverimpressions.blogspot.com/2009/05/sql-server-2008-min-and-max-date-ranges.html) which looked official enough. Actually, it's the date data type that has a range of January 1, 01 through December 31, 9999. Sorry for the confusion. However, anyone who thinks their app will remain on SQL Server 2005 forever hasns't been around for very long and may have some rude surprises in store in the future. Microsoft support for 2005 ends 12 months after the last Service Pack. But you will be dragged into a newer version well before then.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli "the problem" is that `997` at the end of that string: I'd have always expected it to end with `999`, not `997`. I don't want to have to remember magic-values in my head, why can't T-SQL have named-constants like C's `INT_MAX`/`INT_MIN`?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the value like this:

```
PRINT 'The maximum date value '
    + CASE ISDATE('9999-12-31 23:59:59.998') + ISDATE('9999-12-31 23:59:59.999')
        WHEN 0 THEN 'IS LESS THAN'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'EQUALS'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'IS GREATER THAN'
        END
    + ' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.998'
```

Output:

```
The maximum date value EQUALS 9999-12-31 23:59:59.998
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be [in the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)... Up to December 31, 9999.

Answer (score 0):

Because the lower-bounds and upper-bounds of `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2(n)`, `smalldatetime`, etc are tedious to write-out, yet mostly have gotchas, I decided to use [**inline**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining) scalar UDFs to represent the min/max values - so I can either use these UDFs in queries directly, or just run `SELECT dbo.GetMaxDateTime2(7);` in a separate query window and copy-and-paste the literal value over when I can't use a UDF (like in a `CHECK` or `DEFAULT` constraint expression).

...it also includes my own editorialising in the comments :)

```sql
/* The `datetime2(n)` range is the same as `datetimeoffset(n)`'s */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value()
RETURNS datetime2(7)
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( datetime2(7), '0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000' );
END;

GO

/* The `datetime2(n)` range is the same as `datetimeoffset(n)`'s */
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value( @n tinyint )
RETURNS datetime2(7)
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE @n
            WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(0), '9999-12-31 23:59:59'         ) /* 6 bytes */
            WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(1), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9'       ) /* 6 bytes */
            WHEN 2 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(2), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.99'      ) /* 6 bytes */
            WHEN 3 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(3), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999'     ) /* 7 bytes */
            WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(4), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999'    ) /* 7 bytes */
            WHEN 5 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(5), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.99999'   ) /* 8 bytes */
            WHEN 6 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(6), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999'  ) /* 8 bytes */
            WHEN 7 THEN CONVERT( datetime2(7), '9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999' ) /* 8 bytes */
        END;
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMinDateTimeValue()
RETURNS datetime
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( datetime, '1753-01-01 00:00:00.000' ); /* The explanation of significance of the year 1751 can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3310569/159145 */
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaxDateTimeValue()
RETURNS datetime
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( datetime, '9999-12-31 23:59:59.997' ); /* 8 bytes - and yet is inferior to datetime2(7) in every way... how much alcohol was left in the room when the meeting to design the datetime type concluded? */
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMinDateValue()
RETURNS date
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( date, '0001-01-01' ); /* I don't know why MS's docs mention Informatica's lower-bound as 1582-10-15 when it isn't even a Microsoft product. */
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaxDateValue()
RETURNS date
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( date, '9999-12-31' );
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMinSmallDateTimeValue()
RETURNS smalldatetime
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( smalldatetime, '1901-01-01 00:00' );
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetMaxSmallDateTimeValue()
RETURNS smalldatetime
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( smalldatetime, '2079-06-06 23:59' ); /* Technically `'2079-06-06 23:59:29.998'` is valid for input, but it will be rounded-down to 23:59:00. Values of `'2079-06-06 23:59:30'` or higher will cause a conversion error. */
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbadmin.GetMinTimeValue()
RETURNS time(7)
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CONVERT( time, '00:00:00.0000000' ); /* implicitly convertible from `time(7)` to `time(0)`. */
END;

GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbadmin.GetMaxTimeValue( @n tinyint )
RETURNS time(7)
    WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = ON
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        CASE @n
            WHEN 0 THEN CONVERT( time(0), '23:59:59'         ) /* 3 bytes */
            WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT( time(1), '23:59:59.9'       ) /* 3 bytes */
            WHEN 2 THEN CONVERT( time(2), '23:59:59.99'      ) /* 3 bytes */
            WHEN 3 THEN CONVERT( time(3), '23:59:59.999'     ) /* 4 bytes */
            WHEN 4 THEN CONVERT( time(4), '23:59:59.9999'    ) /* 4 bytes */
            WHEN 5 THEN CONVERT( time(5), '23:59:59.99999'   ) /* 5 bytes */
            WHEN 6 THEN CONVERT( time(6), '23:59:59.999999'  ) /* 5 bytes */
            WHEN 7 THEN CONVERT( time(7), '23:59:59.9999999' ) /* 5 bytes */
        END;
END;

GO
```

And here's a table showing the results of those functions for all date+time types in SQL Server:

| Value | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `time(0)` | `00:00:00` | `23:59:59` |
| `time(1)` | `00:00:00.0` | `23:59:59.9` |
| `time(2)` | `00:00:00.00` | `23:59:59.99` |
| `time(3)` | `00:00:00.000` | `23:59:59.999` |
| `time(4)` | `00:00:00.0000` | `23:59:59.9999` |
| `time(5)` | `00:00:00.00000` | `23:59:59.99999` |
| `time(6)` | `00:00:00.000000` | `23:59:59.999999` |
| `time(7)` | `00:00:00.0000000` | `23:59:59.9999999` |
| `date` | `0001-01-01` | `9999-12-31` |
| `datetime` | `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.997` |
| `smalldatetime` | `1901-01-01 00:00:00` | `2079-06-06 23:59:00` |
| `datetime2(0)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59` |
| `datetime2(1)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9` |
| `datetime2(2)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.00` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.99` |
| `datetime2(3)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999` |
| `datetime2(4)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999` |
| `datetime2(5)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.00000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.99999` |
| `datetime2(6)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999` |
| `datetime2(7)` | `0001-01-01 00:00:00.0000000` | `9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999` |

The above table comes from the below query (but transposed to better fit in StackOverflow's uncomfortably narrow post content area). (The `CONVERT` func is needed as some of those functions return `datetime2(7)` or `time(7)` for all `@n` parameters, so you'd see more fractional-seconds digits than you would with the smaller type).

```sql
SELECT
    'Minimum' AS "Value",

    CONVERT( time(0), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(0)",
    CONVERT( time(1), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(1)",
    CONVERT( time(2), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(2)",
    CONVERT( time(3), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(3)",
    CONVERT( time(4), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(4)",
    CONVERT( time(5), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(5)",
    CONVERT( time(6), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(6)",
    CONVERT( time(7), dbo.GetMinTimeValue() ) AS "time(7)",

    dbo.GetMinDateValue()          AS "date",
    dbo.GetMinDateTimeValue()      AS "datetime",
    dbo.GetMinSmallDateTimeValue() AS "smalldatetime",

    CONVERT( datetime2(0), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(0)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(1), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(1)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(2), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(2)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(3), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(3)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(4), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(4)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(5), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(5)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(6), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(6)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(7), dbo.GetMinDateTime2Value() ) AS "datetime2(7)"

UNION

SELECT
    'Maximum' AS "Value",

    CONVERT( time(0), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(0) ) AS "time(0)",
    CONVERT( time(1), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(1) ) AS "time(1)",
    CONVERT( time(2), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(2) ) AS "time(2)",
    CONVERT( time(3), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(3) ) AS "time(3)",
    CONVERT( time(4), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(4) ) AS "time(4)",
    CONVERT( time(5), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(5) ) AS "time(5)",
    CONVERT( time(6), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(6) ) AS "time(6)",
    CONVERT( time(7), dbo.GetMaxTimeValue(7) ) AS "time(7)",

    dbo.GetMaxDateValue()          AS "date",
    dbo.GetMaxDateTimeValue()      AS "datetime",
    dbo.GetMaxSmallDateTimeValue() AS "smalldatetime",

    CONVERT( datetime2(0), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(0) ) AS "datetime2(0)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(1), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(1) ) AS "datetime2(1)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(2), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(2) ) AS "datetime2(2)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(3), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(3) ) AS "datetime2(3)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(4), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(4) ) AS "datetime2(4)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(5), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(5) ) AS "datetime2(5)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(6), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(6) ) AS "datetime2(6)",
    CONVERT( datetime2(7), dbo.GetMaxDateTime2Value(7) ) AS "datetime2(7)";
```

Don't forget that T-SQL **allows** implicit conversions to narrower types when it causes data-loss, it doesn't even give you a warning message (e.g. you can do `DECLARE @maxdt1 datetime2(1) = dbadmin.GetMaxDateTime2Value(7); SELECT @maxdt1;`, **grumble**)